# sublime text: How to paste screenshot into the editor in a markdown file

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using sublime text for writing my markdown files eg: Readme.md

I want to past pictures into the markdown from my screenshot and i want the image to be saved into a subfolder (eg: assets) aside the readme.md and create a line of code like

```
![](./assets/2023-08-10-17-53-56.png)
```

I am able to achieve this in vscode using a package `pasteimage` https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mushan.vscode-paste-image

anything similar in sublime text will be of great help.